# VPN, PPTP or other means to connect to your private LAN through D-Link VPN enabled router from Internet?

Tags: windows-7, router, vpn

We have a small LAN in our house behind a D-Link DSR-500N router, which is supposed to have VPN built in. Now I would like to be able to reach my LAN from outside with my Windows 7 laptop when on the road and for example get to my files which are stored on a QNap NAS. We have a fixed IP Address on the Internet.

I have now been told that we could either choose to use something called PPTP, VPN or using some other sofware, like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), Hamachi or [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com), etc.

But what would be the best in this situation? The most common scenario for me would be to log into our LAN at home and "see" our NAS as if I was actually at home, so as I can use my back up program on my laptop and have it to back up all the files I have changed while being away from home.

What are your suggestions in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to the vendor information your router may act as VPN server and it supports  IPSec, PPTP and L2TP mode. While IPSec is the best of these three it may be difficult to set it up properly. So, I would recommend you to use L2TP as it performs better than PPTP tunnel

If you choose L2TP and you will select the pre-shared key as authentication option then please make this preshared key quite long (more than 10 alpha-numeric and special chars)

Answer (score 0):

If your primary purpose is being able to access files, I recommend OpenSSH.  This is more oriented towards Linux systems, but Windows can handle it just fine.  With OpenSSH, you can enable a tunnel if you need access by third party apps or even use your connection as a proxy.